# Does Azure Communication Services (ACS) calling library limit the length of a video/voice call?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-communication-services

Does Azure Communication Services (ACS) calling library limit the length of a video/voice call?

Once a call is initiated is there a timer on the server side that ends the call after a maximum duration?

Also, is there a client option that can set the maximum length of a call when the call is initiated?

Comment: I don't see anything in the ACS docs about anything regarding a time limit, but I think the more prudent question is why would there be a limit? Wouldn't it be a horrid UX if calls ended abruptly for no apparent reason? Have you asked Azure Support this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you interest in Azure Communication Services! Calls have a limit of 24 hours today - once that limit is reached, the service will terminate the call.

I will make sure this is added to our calling documentation, thank you for the suggestion. If you have scenarios where this 24 hour limit would be an issue, we would love to hear this feedback.

Comment: Is a participantRemoved event and a participantStateChanged event recorded in the call log when the call is terminated?

Comment: Also, is there a client option that can set the maximum length of a call when the call is initiated?

Comment: Confirmed participantRemoved and participantStateChanged events are logged.

Comment: The only solution I can think of would be military use... but you're marketing team is probably all over that... and if they're not they ought to be... I mean you guys just won a DOJ contract